# Capture speaker output

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I've seen that I can capture the microphone and sound-files with elements in the [Windows.Media.Audio namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Audio). I'm looking to capture the **speaker output**, though. For example, I click on something and the system sounds the alert sound - I want to be able to capture that.

Is there any way of doing that using elements in `Windows.Media.Audio` (instead of going more low level into Win32 calls)?

Comment: Not sure if it supports this exact case but you could try [Audio graphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs).

Answer (score 2):

Well, even with "low level Win32 calls", you can't do any loopback recording in UWP.

This is traditionally done with WASAPI, but due to the sandboxed execution of universal applications, you can't open any capture streams on audio render devices in WASAPI.

---

In general, if you dive into COM APIs which have been ported to UWP, you will notice that there have been a lot of restrictions.