# Is loopback recoding supported in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, wasapi

I have been looking around for an answer to this question but there seem to be mixed responses, but is loopback recording (using WASAPI, or something else) supported on all devices in UWP?

I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924716/capture-speaker-output) and [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc4da08c-c6e9-4917-90f9-b7c74e11774c/uwpwhy-is-loopback-recording-not-possible-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop) which seem to tell the opposite of each other.

I wonder, then, what is it? Is loopback recording supported globally in UWP or isn't it? Are there any alternatives to use?

Comment: If you use low-level APIs, your app will no longer be a *universal* Windows application, because you're now tying your app directly to a low-level interface.  You *can* do this, but by doing so you lose any benefit of writing a UWP app.

Comment: @Amy So interfacing with ex. WASAPI would mean I cannot use it on desktop and tablets?

Comment: MeeDj UWP app uses this WASAPI API, you can test it before implement in yours

Comment: Use my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615457/recording-capture-currently-playing-audio

Comment: git hub repository https://github.com/shubdragon/UWP_Playback_Audio_Recording

Comment: @ShubhamSahu I think you're missing what I'm after. I do not want to record audio from the microphone or any input. I want to access the audio that is being played through the speakers.

This does not seem to work in UWP.